# Injecting a @Mock into another @Mock or refactor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CSTest {

    @Mock
    private CachedDb cachedDb;

    @InjectMocks
    private AS aS;

    @InjectMocks
    private CS cS;
}


public class CS extends BS {

     @Inject
     protected AS aS;

     public doStuff() {
         aS.doSomething();
   }

}

public class AS extends BS {
    //bunch of code here
}
```

Is there a way for me to inject the CS inside the test class with the mocked AS that has an injected mock of CachedDb inside of it? The code could be refactored without much effort: I put doSomething inside AS because the behavior is similar to other functions of AS but if this is bad design I can refactor it to a shared utils package or something similar.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit test of `Foo` should only care about mocking the direct dependencies of `Foo`.

You shouldn't assume that AS uses a CachedDb to implement its methods. CS doesn't care. All it does is interacting with a AS. Whether the AS uses a CachedDB or not is irrelevant, as long as its methods do what they're supposed to do.

So, the test of CS should mock AS. Not CachedDB.